# What is the expansion of EIA in "EIA drivers" term?

Tags: drivers

I have to write a driver for my UART.

In that the National Instruments has a document on 16550 chip .There a block which is termed as 'EIA drivers'  .

I want to know the expansion of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Industries_Alliance

cheers